# Python Functions called before referencing error coming up?

Tags: python, function

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#1/usr/bin/env python3
import random
financialPoints = 0
debatePointsT = 0
marginalCheck = random.randint(0,1)
debatePointsTO = 0
Choice = random.randint(0,2)

popularity = 0
name = input("What is your first name")
nameSur = input("What is your surname")

print("This is the political campaign simulator")
chosenParty = input("Choose a party. A - LibDem, B - Labour, C- Tory")

if chosenParty == "C":
    print("You have been elected as a councillor by your fellow peers.")
    marginality = input("They want you to stand as a MP in a seat. Do you want to stand in a safe or marginal seat")
    if marginality == "marginal":
        if marginalCheck == 0:
            print("You have failed to be elected to parliament")
        else:
            print("You are duly elected the MP for your constituency!")
            campaignT()
    else:
        campaignT()





def debateT():

    #My Code
    if marginality == "safe":
          campaignT()


def campaign():
    #My Code
    if elected == True:
           debateT()
```

It tells me that I have called a function before referencing it, but I need it to be there for me to run another part of the code, as you can see above. Is there a way in python for me to get to functions to go side by side, or something like that?

Comment: What do you mean, "I need it to be there"? Was the bulk of the code given to you and you are only allowed/expected to fill in the function bodies?

Comment: @Anish, you are defining a function `campaign` in the bottom but are calling the function `campaignT` in the if-else block. Apart from that, place the functions at the head of the file.

Comment: i need  it to be there so I can use the variables

Answer (score 0):

The function definition must come before the code that references it.

Move `debateT()` and `campaign()` to the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Move your defined functions to the top of your file like:

```
#1/usr/bin/env python3
import random
financialPoints = 0
debatePointsT = 0
marginalCheck = random.randint(0,1)
debatePointsTO = 0
Choice = random.randint(0,2)

def debateT():

#My Code
    if marginality == "safe":
        campaignT()


def campaign():
    #My Code
    if elected == True:
        debateT()

popularity = 0
name = input("What is your first name")
nameSur = input("What is your surname")

print("This is the political campaign simulator")
chosenParty = input("Choose a party. A - LibDem, B - Labour, C- Tory")

if chosenParty == "C":
    print("You have been elected as a councillor by your fellow peers.")
    marginality = input("They want you to stand as a MP in a seat. Do you want to stand in a safe or marginal seat")
    if marginality == "marginal":
        if marginalCheck == 0:
            print("You have failed to be elected to parliament")
        else:
            print("You are duly elected the MP for your constituency!")
            campaignT()
    else:
        campaignT()
```